# vagrant plugin install error

Tags: vagrant, gem, amazon-linux

I'm trying to install a vagrant plugin

```
$ vagrant plugin install vagrant-aws
```

which exits with this error:

```
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.3.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

When I try that command

```
$ gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.3.1'
```

It fails because the version of libxml2 I have is incompatible (requires < 2.9.0 and I have 2.9.1 installed with the system. I cannot downgrade or uninstall it because it has a million dependencies.)

I've gotten nokogiri to successfully install with:

```
$ gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries=true --with-xml2-include=/usr/include/libxml2/
```

Yet when I run the `vagrant plugin install` command again, it still exits with the same error.

How can I either a) get vagrant to recognize that that gem is already installed or b) get vagrant to use the `--use-system-libraries=true` etc. install parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$ export NOKOGIRI_USE_SYSTEM_LIBRARIES=true
$ vagrant plugin install vagrant-aws
```

Source: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/3769